# Reordering rows based on sequence

Tags: r, sequence

With the following data I would like to rearrange rows within each unique ProjectID.

```
Data <- data.frame(ProjectID=c(123,123,123,124,125,125,126,126,126,126,128,129),
               Value=c(1,4,7,3,8,9,2,5,3,7,2,6),
               Sequence=c(1,3,2,1,3,2,1,1,4,2,2,4))
```

Within each unique ProjectID, if the Sequence contains either "1,3,2" or "1,4,2" I want to reorder the rows to follow "3,1,2" or "4,1,2", respectively.

In ProjectID 126, there are four observations with Sequence 1,1,4,2, so the expected result should show 1,4,1,2.

How can I accomplish this?

Result should be as follows

```
Result <- data.frame(ProjectID=c(123,123,123,124,125,125,126,126,126,126,128,129),
                 Value=c(4,1,7,3,8,9,2,3,5,7,2,6),
                 Sequence=c(3,1,2,1,3,2,1,4,1,2,2,4))
```

Comment: What about other cases i.e. 2, 3, 1 or 2, 1, 3 or 1, 2, 3 etc

Comment: @akrun I'd only be interested in those two cases (1,3,2 and 1,4,2).

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(rbind,
    lapply(split(Data, Data$ProjectID), function(a){
        if(identical(a$Sequence, c(1,4,2))){
            a[match(a$Sequence, c(4,1,2)),]
        }else if(identical(a$Sequence, c(1,3,2))){
            a[match(a$Sequence, c(3,1,2)),]
        }else{
            a
        }
    }
)
)
#      ProjectID Value Sequence
#123.2       123     4        3
#123.1       123     1        1
#123.3       123     7        2
#124         124     3        1
#125.5       125     8        3
#125.6       125     9        2
#126.8       126     5        4
#126.7       126     2        1
#126.9       126     7        2
#128         128     2        2
#129         129     6        4
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Had a theoretical for your code. What if for each Project ID, the Sequence in question were not the only rows in that ProjectID. So for example, what if ProjectID 126 had 4 rows with Sequence 1,1,4,2 instead of 3 rows.                                                           Data <- data.frame(ProjectID=c(123,123,123,124,125,125,126,126,126,126,128,129),
                   Value=c(1,4,7,3,8,9,2,5,5,7,2,6),
                   Sequence=c(1,3,2,1,3,2,1,1,4,2,2,4))